# What is the alternative way to insert bulk records into oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i am using oracle CURSORs to iterate huge volume of records to insert from one table to another table. I found that it is taking very long time to insert. Is there any alternative way to process bulk records without using CURSORs. 
Here is the activities that i am performing.

```
CURSOR FIRST_TAB(bu_emp_id IN Number) IS
  SELECT * FROM FIRST_TABLE lst
  where lst.emp_id =  bu_emp_id;

v_first FIRST_TAB%ROWTYPE;

CURSOR SECOND_TAB(bu_emp_id IN Number) IS
  SELECT * FROM SECOND_TABLE 2nd WHERE 2nd.emp_id= bu_emp_id;

v_second SECOND_TAB%ROWTYPE;

CURSOR THIRD_TAB(bu_emp_id IN Number) IS
  SELECT * FROM THIRD_TABLE 3rd WHERE 3rd.emp_id = bu_emp_id;

v_third THIRD_TAB%ROWTYPE;
------------------------------------------------------------------------

open FIRST_TAB(bu_emp_id);
  loop
    fetch FIRST_TAB into r_first;
    exit when FIRST_TAB %NOTFOUND;

-- iNSERT STATEMENT-------

  open SECOND_TAB(bu_emp_id);
     loop
       fetch SECOND_TAB into v_second;
       exit when SECOND_TAB %NOTFOUND;

-- iNSERT STATEMENT-------

       open THIRD_TAB(bu_emp_id);
         loop
           fetch THIRD_TAB into v_third ;
           exit when THIRD_TAB %NOTFOUND;

-- iNSERT STATEMENT-------

         end loop;
      close THIRD_TAB;
    end loop;
    close SECOND_TAB;
  end loop;
  close FIRST_TAB;
```

Comment: I've formatted your code. Please do this by highlighting the relevant section and clicking the `{}` button when creating your question.

Comment: `INSERT ... SELECT` will be a lot faster than using cursors.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You code won't work at all. Names beginning with a number have to be explicitly cased using `"2nd"` and your first cursor seems to need a parameter but this doesn't exist... As a_horse_with_no_name suggests you should probably just use a simple `insert`.

Comment: Hi Ben, Actually i have missed this parameter...Now i have modified.

Answer (score 3):

Find a way do it in straight SQL. It is not obvious from your example whether your data lends itself to that approach, but strive to do this. You're not going to improve on doing things entirely in one statement in the engine.